# Is there Rstudio in the Fedora 16 Repositories?

Tags: linux, r, fedora

I would like to use Rstudio as IDE for R applications, but at the moment I don't see it in the repository, before installing it from .rpm, could someone tell me if Rstudio is in FEdora 16 Repos ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[As shown in Fedora's admindb tool, Rstudio is not available in Fedora's repositories.](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/apps/search/%2atudio%2a)

Comment: Awesome. A downvote for a link to the canonical source of info about what's in Fedora. Don't you people have anything better to do?

Comment: It might have been a downvote for snark (deserved though it may have been).

Comment: I downvoted for posting just a link and giving a much too short answer. In my view this is comparable to answering using let me google that for you, which is generally not accepted on SO. Other people like dirk took some more time to answer this question in a more respectful manner. The fact that the question is basic ane easy to google does not make it unacceptable for SO.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, I canceled the downvote.

Comment: @Paul: What for? All I did was say "No." with more words.

Comment: You answer was good, the manner in which you formulated it was what I downvoted for. The answer looks more respectful now, thus the cancellation.

Answer (score 6):

RStudio is not in the repos of any distro, but available in suitable .deb or .rpm format [from their site's handy download page](http://rstudio.org/download) in either the desktop or server variant.

For rpm, support is listed for Red Hat / CentOs which seems to imply it would also work on newer Fedora releases.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using `yum`, the Fedora package manager, to do the search for you? After all this is what a distro's package manager is for. If you don't like command line apps, use the Add/Remove Software front-end to `yum` (Applications > System Tools in Gnome 3)

```
$ yum search studio
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * rpmfusion-free: mirrors.coreix.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirrors.coreix.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: mirrors.coreix.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirrors.coreix.net
 * updates: mirror01.th.ifl.net
========================================================================= N/S Matched: studio ==========================================================================
librawstudio.i686 : Rawstudio backend library
librawstudio.x86_64 : Rawstudio backend library
librawstudio-devel.i686 : librawstudio development files
librawstudio-devel.x86_64 : librawstudio development files
synfigstudio.i686 : Vector-based 2D animation studio
synfigstudio.x86_64 : Vector-based 2D animation studio
synfigstudio-devel.i686 : Development files for synfigstudio
synfigstudio-devel.x86_64 : Development files for synfigstudio
agistudio.x86_64 : AGI integrated development environment
anchorman.x86_64 : The recording-studio-in-a-box
anjuta-doc.noarch : Documentation for Anjuta DevStudio
hercstudio.x86_64 : GUI front-end to the Hercules mainframe Emulator
lib3ds.i686 : 3D Studio file format library
lib3ds.x86_64 : 3D Studio file format library
lib3ds-devel.i686 : 3D Studio file format library
lib3ds-devel.x86_64 : 3D Studio file format library
lib3ds-tools.x86_64 : 3D Studio file format library
lmms.x86_64 : Linux MultiMedia Studio
monkeystudio.x86_64 : Free cross-platform Qt 4 IDE
rawstudio.x86_64 : Read, manipulate and convert digital camera raw images
texstudio.x86_64 : A feature-rich editor for LaTeX documents
zint-qt.i686 : Zint Barcode Studio
zint-qt.x86_64 : Zint Barcode Studio

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Comment: Yum only searches the enabled repositories. There may be others worth using.

Comment: The answer was down voted for snark.  The reason why the person cannot use yum or dnf is that these tools do not answer the question of the poster. An informative answer is that (https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/81133/rstudio-installation-fails-on-fedora-23/) It's published on its web site https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ The last one is the one. Once downloaded you can install it with **sudo dnf install rstudio-0.99.491-x86_64.rpm** (just tested it, if no R-core installed it will install it)

Comment: @greg the question was is Rstudio available in the Fedora 16 repositories? not is there an rpm available somewhere. You have low tolerances for snark, but you are patently wrong if you think I didn't answer the question. You answered a different question, Rstudio won't be updated as one might expect with packages in a proper repo. And yes I do know how to install rpms using yum but as the OP was asking about repos it's not unreasonable to presume they wanted a repo, not a random rpm!

Comment: @GavinSimpson a Google query brought me here.  Just like the original question, I was looking for the secret hand shake to find the RPM package: r-studio, R:studio, r-studio-devel, etc.  My objection to this answer is that I already tried several dnf queries.  The flat out answer r studio is not available in Fedora repositories.  I got that.  That still does not answer my overall question nor the original poster's intent (and apparently poorly formed question) of what is the secret to get going with R Studio on an RPM based system such as Fedora?

Comment: @greg you can't complain that I didn't answer the question not asked! Nor that I didn't answer your question here when it wasn't the question asked.  There is no secret to getting R installed on a Red hat system; there's a big difference between installing an rpm and installing from a repo, even if the command to do so is somewhat similar. You've got to download the file and it will never update so you are responsible for that. That's why people prefer repos! I can only answer the question asked; OP didn't say they need help to install Rstudio.

Answer (score 1):

The RPMs listed on the site page don't include full source -- including the SPEC file used to create the RPM package.  We have little means of ensuring the safety of the RPM build, and I'd recommend avoiding the RPM build altogether until we have the full source.

I notice that PLD appears to have built a package, too, and their SPEC may be used to cook up a working SPEC we can use to rebuild a verifiable RHEL5 RPM -- as well as start on a Fedora build.  I don't believe that's the shortest route to a proper Fedora package in the least amount of time, but it's the only one to a build that's verifiable at each step.  YMMV, and good luck.